# Override/Upgrade application downloaded outside Google Play with new version uploaded and installed from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Currently, I have downloadable APK outside of Google Play and thousands of users that have downloaded and used it.
 
My question is:

Can I upload the same application to Google Play (maybe with the same name, but with greater version), so that my customers can download the new version from Google Play Store that will override and upgrade the current one, which was downloaded from outside?

Comment: If you use the same signature and package name, your customers should be able to update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the things that make your app unique are the signature and the package name.

If the app in Google Play has the same signature and same package and a versionCode greater than the apk installed then it will upgrade the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload it on Google Play store but it should be a signed apk and you should have all the data unique like description, etc.

Comment: Which means not possible.

Comment: If the apk which was uploaded on other site was a signed one not the debug one then it can be used otherwise not.

Comment: Neha can you please explain more  what does it mean:
signed apk?
if it is self signed?

Comment: If the apk you uploaded on the website was a signed one. You can check this url https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html it shows how a signed apk is created.